# Calculate "position in run" in SQL

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table of consecutive ids (integers, 1 ... n), and values (integers), like this:

Input Table:

```
id value
-- -----
 1   1
 2   1
 3   2
 4   3
 5   1
 6   1
 7   1
```

Going down the table i.e. in order of increasing id, I want to count how many times in a row the same value has been seen consecutively, i.e. the position in a run:

Output Table:

```
id value position in run  
-- ----- ---------------  
 1   1          1
 2   1          2
 3   2          1
 4   3          1
 5   1          1
 6   1          2
 7   1          3
```

Any ideas? I've searched for a combination of windowing functions including lead and lag, but can't come up with it. Note that the same value can appear in the value column as part of different runs, so partitioning by value may not help solve this. I'm on Hive 1.2.

Comment: I'm pretty sure using a variable for representing the previous value, and another variable for keeping track of its run position would be the ideal solution for generating such an output. Honestly though, I'd modify the schema to calculate this kind of stuff when it's inserted/update/delete to help speed up selects.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a difference of row numbers approach to classify consecutive *same* values into one group. Then a row number function to get the desired positions in each group.

Query to assign groups (Running this will help you understand how the groups are assigned.)

```
select t.*
,row_number() over(order by id) - row_number() over(partition by value order by id) as rnum_diff
from tbl t
```

Final Query using `row_number` to get positions in each group assigned with the above query.

```
select id,value,row_number() over(partition by value,rnum_diff order by id) as pos_in_grp
from (select t.*
      ,row_number() over(order by id) - row_number() over(partition by value order by id) as rnum_diff
      from tbl t
     ) t
```

Comment: Excellent!!.. this is somewhat complex and you solved it.

Comment: hi @Vamsi.. could you pls give a try at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53752311/spark-window-functions-that-depend-on-itself

Comment: @stack0114106 .. been thinking about this..couldn't find a way to solve this yet :) possible with recursive cte in SQL..however, it is not supported in Spark SQL and Hive.

Comment: thanks for your reply..whatever way you are solving..fine..pls let me know once you complete