# Continuous dates to create case #

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I am trying to add case # based on Customer ID and Start & End Dates.  As long as there is no break in the date ranges for a customer, same case # will be applied. See sample data. Is there way accomplish this in Teradata SQL?

[image: data sample]

Comment: I see an image, not sample data. (The image does display sample data.) It is **strongly** preferred that you supply data as inserts or as a simple text table (e.g. use this https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ )

Comment: It would be simpler to look into Teradata normalize and period functionality, to merge those contiguous rows together.

Comment: What if those ranges overlap, e.g. end date 2018-04-18 and next start date 2018-14-16?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a number using `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when enddate = prev_enddate + interval '1' day
                then 0 else 1
           end) over (partition by customerid order by startdate
                     ) as result
from (select t.*,
             lag(enddate) over (partition by customerid order by startdate) as prev_enddate
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Gordon.. could  you pls give a try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53752311/spark-window-functions-that-depend-on-itself in sql